# Custom title on sharing direct link of a GIF file on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

Whenever i share a direct-link of an GIF from giphy.com on facebook.
 Facebook shows "GIPHY" written as a title to the shared gif.

[image: GIPHY]

Generally, its just shows hostname of the site when sharing direct-link from other sites. For example "www.ohmagif.com" in below image

[image: Other sites]

How does the giphy site does this magic?